# Площадь правильного шестиугольника

Tags: c

На e-olimp есть задача в которой нужно найти площадь правильного шестиугольника по данной стороне: [Площадь шестиугольника](http://www.e-olimp.com/problems/2013)

Моё решение не проходит на сервере, отображая надпись неправильный ответ. Помогите разобраться.
Программа выглядит так.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {

long long int L, S = 0;
 scanf("%lld", &L);
 S = ((3 * sqrt(3)) / 2) * ((2 * L) / sqrt(sqrt(3))) * ((2 * L) / sqrt(sqrt(3)));
 printf("%lld\n", S);
return 0;
 }
```

Comment: поправь этот вырвиглаз..

Answer (score 4):

Смотрим в вики [Правильный шестиугольник](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA), получаем формулу (3 * sqrt(3) / 2) * (L*L). "три корня из трёх, делённое на два, умноженное на сторону в квадрате".
Откуда твои формулы я не совсем понимаю.

P.S. дополнение из комментов (alexlz и avp). Возьмите L и S как double, формат sqrt:

```
double sqrt (double x);
```

P.P.S. Я понял, что вы имели ввиду. Сначала считайте переменную L, вычислите сторону X по формуле (так как по условию L не является стороной, а служит для её вычисления):

```
double X = ((2 * L) / sqrt(sqrt(3)));
```

А затем найдите S:

```
double S = (3 * sqrt(3) / 2) * (X*X).
```

Comment: Вы прочитайте условие и поймёте, чему равна сторона шестиугольника.

Comment: @MahovIV непонятно, что Вы хотели сказать. @spirit правильно указал ошибку (одну). Вторая -- тип переменной S (д.б. double или float). Да и L лучше того же типа.

Comment: @MahovIV, советую **внимательно** посмотреть на `man sqrt`.

(подсказка: типы данных).

Comment: @alexlz да, тип я не заметил, но причиной тому было ужасное форматирование кода, которое уже поправили=)

Comment: поправил ответ, кажется я понял, что нужно. Опять виной оформление и невнятное "link text"

Comment: Там нужно выводить как целое число.

Comment: См. `man 3 round`.

Comment: Я так и чувствовал, что к программированию (в смысле умения манипулировать структурами данных) эта задача не относится, а место ей на форуме Математика.

@alexlz, а перенесите свой комментарий в ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Каюсь, я (тоже) не заметил, что L -- не сторона шестиугольника. А там получается интересней (всё, что в знаменателе -- сокращается). и соответственно арифметика вполне может быть целой (при целом L):

```
 S = 6 * L * L;
```

[[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp) сделано. Вообще должно было уже насторожить такое значение. как корень четвёртой степени из трёх. Это ж-ж-ж (такие значения) в задачах зря не появляются